# How to speed up sqllite transaction (write data)?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, transactions

I am currently self learning (2 weeks) `vb` with `visual studio 2015 express`.

I am trying to `import` selected data from an `access database` to a `datagridview`.  I want to write that data inside `sqllite database`.

My code is shown below. It works but I am not sure if the transaction is set up correctly. Also I am not sure if I have to use a transaction when writing to the `sqllite DB`. The operation seems slow and I think that it could be quicker.

Do I have the transaction set up correctly?

My code is:

```
    Dim con As String = "Data Source=C:\clients.db;Version=3;"
    Dim sqConnection As New SQLiteConnection(con)
    Dim sqCommand As New SQLiteCommand()
    sqCommand.Connection = sqConnection
    Dim myTrans As SQLiteTransaction '= sqConnection.BeginTransaction()
    sqConnection.Open()
    ' Start a local transaction
    myTrans = sqConnection.BeginTransaction()
    ' Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
    sqCommand.Transaction = myTrans

    Try
        sqCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Clients (Registered, Name, Number, Details) VALUES (@Registered, @Name, @Number, @Details)"
        sqCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registered", row.Cells(1).Value)
        sqCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells(2).Value)
        sqCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", row.Cells(3).Value)
        sqCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", row.Cells(4).Value)                
        sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myTrans.Commit()
        Application.DoEvents()
    Finally
        sqConnection.Close()

    End Try
```

I have looked at various questions/replies which left me even more confused. I am getting nowhere fast and seem to be going in circles.

Comment: If you re-open the database and create a transaction for each record you're writing, it's no wonder that it's slow.

Comment: @CL. could you explain where I have gone wrong please ?

Comment: In the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a transaction to add a record to the database.  I would use a transaction when you are doing something that preforms multiple operations on the database. If for some reason something goes wrong during the process the transaction can roll back the changes to the database

Answer (score 0):

Resolved I moved the myTrans.Commit() to just before the End Sub and now the insert is twice as fast..